# Is it possible to split string by using key to number array?

Tags: batch-file

I've a text file that contains the data like this

```
response_list { time_range_stat { start_time_usecs: 1476763290000000 sampling_interval_secs: 30 value_list: 0 value_list: 1000000 value_list: 1000000 value_list: 205759 value_list: 139172. . . } }
```

I want to get the value of **the value_list key** and find the average by using batch script.

It is possible to do that?

If it's possible, advise me please.

Comment: Is that supposed to be JSON?  Is the data truly all on a single line with only a space delimiting values?

Comment: Is there always 5 value lists?  Is there always periods after the last one?

Comment: @Squashman No, there isn’t. Some file is contains hundreds of the value_list key.

Comment: @rojo Yes , the data truly on a single line and a space delimiting.

Comment: I don't think you are showing us an accurate representation of how the data ends.  So you did not answer my second question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything's possible with enough beer.  I advise you to [read about string manipulation](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php).  In the future, you should also post code demonstrating that you've attempted to solve the problem on your own.

For now, hopefully the script below will be enough to get you started.  Be advised that the string manipulation expects the data to match the format you have above.  If indeed there are no ellipses signaling the end of your data, you might want to replace `. . .` with `}` on line 10.

Also note that Batch math is limited to 32-bit signed integers.  If the total value of all `value_list` values combined exceeds 2147483647, you're going to get an erroneous value.  A different scripting language might be preferable.

Good luck!

```js
@echo off & setlocal

rem // populate %data% variable
set /P "data=" <"text file that contains the data.txt"

rem // strip everything prior to the first value_list
set "data=%data:* value_list: =%"

rem // strip everything after the ellipses.
set data=%data:. . .=&rem;%

rem // init counters
set /a values=0, total=0

rem // replace "value_list:" with a delimiter that can be split by "for"
for %%I in (%data: value_list: =;%) do set /a values += 1, total += %%I

rem // average values.  Note: Batch math rounds the result to the nearest integer.
set /a avg = total / values

rem // output result
echo average: %avg%
```

Comment: plus one just for the first phrase! **`:)`**

Comment: @rojo It's working! , Thank you very much. I owe you some beer now.